# Can Wordpress get_template_part based off viewport size?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I was wondering if I can load a different wordpress template part based on viewport size.

eg. if viewport is smaller than 740px load`<?php get_template_part( '/mobiletemplate'); ?>`

if viewport is larger than 741px load`<?php get_template_part( '/desktoptemplate'); ?>`

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this code

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) 
{
    get_template_part( '/mobiletemplate');
}
else
{
    get_template_part( '/desktoptemplate');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the viewport size using only PHP. You'll need JS for that purpose.

**JS solution**

Get the viewport and send an ajax request to update the template's part accordingly.

Further reading:

- [screen.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)
- [screen.height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/height)

**CSS Solution**

Regarding to responsive design (adjusted by screen's size), a better practice would be to have one template and by using CSS (media queries) it would be adjusted to each screen size.

Another option is to load both of the template's parts and using CSS (media queries) hide one of the templates regarding the viewport size. For instance:

```
.hide-on-desktop{
  display: none;
}

only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .hide-on-desktop{
    display: block;
  }
  .hide-on-mobile{
    display: none;
  }
}
```